# iPhone App opens in Landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

My universal app (targeting 4.3) opens in landscape and then rotates to portrait, if user is holding device in portrait orientation.  This doesn't occur on the Pad.  Also I can't see anything in the plist or code that would make this happen.  Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution.

EDIT:  Haven't found a solution but the issue appears to be the order of the "Supported interface orientations" in the plist.  This doesn't affect the Pad.

On the phone, if the first item in the plist is landscape, then the app will open in landscape regardless of the phone's actual orientation.  Once loaded, if the phone is in portrait, the app will rotate to portrait.  And vice versa, if the first item is portrait, then the app will open in portrait.  If phone orientation is landscape it will rotate when loaded.

I'm wondering if this is just an undocumented feature.

Comment: What exactly your issue is?? Your question is confusing me.. Please elaborate.

Comment: Have you coded anything which detects orientation of a device?? If yes please post code..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==1)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this actually made it worse.  Dropped the snippet in the appdelegate and now it goes landscape to portrait and then back to landscape in the blick of an eye.  I'll need to dig further